# Dynamic column sizes in relational databases

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, column-sizing

Assume we have a system which includes a relational database (Say, MySQL or Oracle, for instance) which is populated by a scheduled job which consumes data from an external API. Also assume there are no guarantees for the size of data (e.g. size of a particular value of a json) coming from the API.

In this kind of a scenario, what is the best practice to determine a proper column size for a particular attribute populated using data coming from the API? Is it an apt way to dynamically (programmatically) adjust the column size based on incoming data, or do we assign a relatively larger size to accommodate incoming larger data?

Thank You.

Comment: Does the [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) corresponding to `LONGTEXT` (~2^32) probably enough? (same in [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/)). So if this works, don't worry about autosizeing. You aren't saving/loosing data or storage that way.

Comment: The column of JSON type have no size/length spec. part.

Comment: The JSON is not persisted as it is. What's persisted are the values inside JSON in different columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [A]ssume there are no guarantees for the size of data (e.g. size of a particular value of a json) coming from the API.
>
> In this kind of a scenario, what is the best practice to determine a proper column size for a particular attribute populated using data coming from the API?

In Oracle, you can use a `CLOB` data type.

> Say, [...] Oracle, for instance

In Oracle, a `VARCHAR2` column is limited to 4000 bytes in the SQL scope. If you have no guarantees about the size of the data then use a `CLOB`. In Oracle 19c a `CLOB` datatype has [a limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/datatype-limits.html#GUID-963C79C9-9303-49FE-8F2D-C8AAF04D3095) of 4GB * `DB_BLOCK_SIZE` initialization parameter (which give a total size of 8 TB to 128 TB). If you are exceeding that limit then you should seriously consider re-working how you are consuming the data.